# In Python, what is the difference between the 'urllib library' and the 'socket library'?

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

I'm learning network programming basics, and there is a question I don't know how to answer in my assignment.

How is 'urllib library' different from 'socket library' in Python? 
How can I explain it clearly?

Answer (score 12):

[`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) is much higher level.

[`socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) provides low-level access to many different kinds of sockets, which you can use to communicate over any port and protocol.  For example, you could use it for email, SSH, remote desktop, etc.  You can also use it for to listen on a port (for a server).  Almost all Python networking libraries, including `urllib`, use `socket` somehow.

`urllib` is specialized to particular uses of sockets, namely the client side of the HTTP (and optionally TLS) and FTP protocols, typically (but not always) using ports 80, 443, or 21.

Comment: Additionally, `urllib` is client-only, while `socket` supports clients, servers, and whatever else.  It's easier to just say that all the Internet-facing stuff you do in Python probably goes through `socket`.

Comment: @Mike, thanks. Those are both good points. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, Thank you Mathew and Mike very much.

Answer (score 0):

In my basic mindset, urllib require you less code line and more consistent to attach to the server. In fact, socket may take you much more time to access the internet and require you more code to process through your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).